# Remove meta description on certain pages

Tags: php, functions, wp-head

Wordpress renders a meta description tag with the content of the blog post as the value for the description.

I already generated in the `header.php` what I want the description to be, no matter what. However, the old one is still in there. I checked `single-post.php` and `header.php` and there is nothing rendering the meta description. So it HAS to be the `wp_head()` function.

Is there anyway I can put something in my `functions.php` or something to ensure that on certain pages the meta description is removed from `wp_head()`?

Comment: Have you tried switching themes to make certain it isn't your theme, and have you tried disabling all your plugins to see if any of them are setting it? single-post.php and header.php are not the only places in a theme one could set a meta description, and the theme is not the only option either.

Comment: It's not the theme, seeing that I have the same theme on my test site and it doesn't do that. I literally have no clue where the meta tag is coming from. I don't want to disable all the plugins on my main site as it is a large website that I hate to see go down.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove the existing description tag with the following code:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Put the above snippet inside the same function you are using to conditionally add a new tag so there is always only a single description tag at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remote `<meta name="description" content="" />` in html head, Add

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'description');
```

into your function.php.

Comment: I only want to remove it on one of the pages, not all of them. Also, is there a way to change the description too if need be?

Comment: One way of doing what you want is to create a specific page.php template for the page and run the `remove_action` on the page after `wp_head();`. On your second question, I actually use a plugin (i decided too much trouble to write my own code) called easy-wp-meta-description which allows me to create the meta description content on each post for better SEO score.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `get_header();`, not `wp_head();`.

Comment: I did the remove_action function on the page after get_header() and it didn't change anything. Also, I have TONS of posts, so that would take FOREVER to do. Insteead, I wrote a code that generated a meta description tag. It's working fine, just got to get rid of the old meta description tag cause it's confusing google.

Answer (score 0):

For change the content of the meta description:

```
<?php 
$description = '';
if( is_single() or is_page() ){
    global $post;
    $description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->meta_key, true );
} ?>
<?php if( $description ): ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php print $description; ?>"
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. However, all that does is add another meta tag, not change the current one.